# Need help working out "Total" button for fence price calculator

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I'm writing a program that calculates the cost of building a fence. The fence can either be built out of `Chainlink ($25)` or `Wood ($35)`, can include an addition of 1- 3 gates (`each individual one costing $165`) and includes a `tax` of `9%`.
I've gotten almost all of it done, however now my problem is figuring out what to set the total `"onclick"` as . I currently have it read as `"'total = "fence_function()"'"`, but I'm pretty sure this is wrong. I also don't for the life of me know what to set `"onchange"` as.
Here's the code in full:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<style>
        body{background-color:#e8ddcb}
        h1{color:#093969}
        table{border:#035567}

</style>
    
  <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content_Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 
 <title> Fence Price Calculator </title>
  </head>
    
  <body>
      <script>
          
        var some_variable = "initial string information";
        var some_other_variable = 56;
  var length=0;
  var width=0;
  var gates=0;
  var total=0;
  var fence_type="Chainlink";
        var price=0;
        

  function fence_function()
  {
            length = document.fen2.len.value;
            width = document.fen3.wid.value;
   var perimeter = 2*length+2*width;
   if(fence_type == "Wooden")
   {
    price = 35*perimeter;
   }
   if(fence_type == "Chainlink")
   {
    price = 25*perimeter;
   }
   price = 165*gates+price;
   price = price*.09+price; 
            disp.value = price;
  }

      </script>
      <center><h1>Fence Price Calculator</h1></center>
        <br>
      
     <center> <table border="1" color= #CDB380>
          <tr>
              <td><i style="color:#036564">Length</i></td>
              <td><i style="color:#036564">Fences</i></td>
              <td><i style="color:#036564">Gates</i></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><form name="fen2">
                  <input type="text" size ="5" name="len">
              </form></td>
              <td><button form = "fen" onclick= 'fence_type = "Chainlink"' > Chainlink </button></td>
              <td><button form = "fen" onclick= 'gates = 1' > 1 </button></td>
              <td><button form = "fen" onclick= 'some_variable = "initial string information"; 
                          some_other_variable = 56; disp.value = "0.00"' > Clear </button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><i style="color:#036564">Width</i></td>
              <td><button form = "fen" onclick= 'fence_type = "Wooden"' > Wooden </button></td>
              <td><button form = "fen" onclick= 'gates = 2' > 2 </button></td>
              <td><button form = "fen" onclick= 'total = "fence_function()"' > Total </button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><form name="fen3">
                  <input type="text" size ="5" name="wid">
              </form></td>
              <td></td>
              <td><button form = "fen" onclick= 'gates = 3' > 3 </button></td>
              <td><form name="fen">
                  <input type="text" id="disp" value="0.00" size="5" onchange=' '/>
              </form></td>
          </tr>
      </table> </center>
         
  </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: I think you are using 'total="fence_function()"' to calculate total value and update text in text box which is wrong. Refer http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp for information about calling a funcion in onclick event and check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp for changing the value of text box dynamically in javascript.

Answer (score -1):

To display the total in the "disp" textbox, you need to change the onclick of the Total button to simply call the function:

```
<button onclick="fence_function();">Total</button>
```

The setting of the "disp" is done in the fence_function function. You don't need anything in the onchange event of the textbox, and given that it's a calculated value and not a user entered value, you could consider changing the "disp" element to a span or div rather than an input and set its value by:

```
document.getElementById("disp").innerText = total;
```

Or you can just set the readonly property on the textbox.